# Polymer bundler does not output node_modules folder with custom bundles

Tags: polymer, polymer-cli

Using `polymer-cli` 1.7.7, bundling a Polymer 3 app for esm, es6 and es5 support does not output `node_modules`. As a consequence, dependencies such as `@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs` are not found when the bundles are served with `prpl-server`.

Here is a small example for reproduction:

https://github.com/lpellegr/polymer-bundler-bundle-issue

This example is based on the original polymer 3 app template generated by `polymer-cli init`. The configuration file `polymer.json` has been edited to generate esm, es6 and es5 bundles as suggested on the following resource:

https://polymer.github.io/pwa-starter-kit/building-and-deploying/

If you run `polymer build`, the output directory does not contain include a `node_modules` directory and thus not the JavaScript file for webcomponentjs:

```
build/
├── es5-bundled
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── push-manifest.json
│   ├── service-worker.js
│   └── src
│       └── _element
│           └── _element.js
├── es6-bundled
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── push-manifest.json
│   ├── service-worker.js
│   └── src
│       └── _element
│           └── _element.js
├── esm-bundled
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── push-manifest.json
│   ├── service-worker.js
│   └── src
│       └── _element
│           └── _element.js
└── polymer.json
```

If you remove the `builds` option from `polymer.json` (thus reverting to the default template), then all looks good, the right `node_modules` folder is outputted:

```
build/ └── default
    ├── index.html
    ├── node_modules
    │   ├── @polymer
    │   │   └── polymer
    │   │       ├── lib
    │   │       │   ├── elements
    │   │       │   │   └── dom-module.js
    │   │       │   ├── mixins
    │   │       │   │   ├── element-mixin.js
    │   │       │   │   ├── properties-changed.js
    │   │       │   │   ├── properties-mixin.js
    │   │       │   │   ├── property-accessors.js
    │   │       │   │   ├── property-effects.js
    │   │       │   │   └── template-stamp.js
    │   │       │   └── utils
    │   │       │       ├── async.js
    │   │       │       ├── boot.js
    │   │       │       ├── case-map.js
    │   │       │       ├── html-tag.js
    │   │       │       ├── mixin.js
    │   │       │       ├── path.js
    │   │       │       ├── resolve-url.js
    │   │       │       ├── settings.js
    │   │       │       └── style-gather.js
    │   │       └── polymer-element.js
    │   └── @webcomponents
    │       └── webcomponentsjs
    │           └── webcomponents-loader.js
    └── src
        ├── _element
        │   └── _element.js
        └── test-app
            └── test-app.js
```

Is there something wrong with my `polymer.json`? Is it a bug with `polymer-bundler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `polymer.json` file doesn't include the information that the Polymer CLI uses to decide what to include in the build.

Adding the missing lines as per the PWA Starter Kit makes it work, for example:

```
"entrypoint": "index.html",
"extraDependencies": [
    "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/**"
],
```

Comment: Thanks! It will teach me not to pay enough attention at the original file.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I've tried everything. Why must this all be so hard...